# Como usar Google Glass no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando instalar o Google Glass no meu Android Studio, mas não estou conseguindo. Quando crio um projeto novo, ele não me fornece a opção do glass e informa que não esta instalado.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Já tentei abrir o SDK pra ver se achava o glass pra download, mas não achei. Todos os recursos que possui no SDK eu tenho instalado e atualizado. A única coisa que achei sobre o glass foi isso:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: A API8 que escolheste em cima é compatível com o glass? Experimenta por uma API mais recente a ver se a opção fica liberada. Deve ser esse o problema.

Comment: Aquela API é referente a telefone e tablet, tentei aqui e não deu, mas de qualquer forma, mesmo quando deixo ela desmarcada o glass não aparece disponível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start), é necessário instalar a SDK do Android 4.4.2(API 19) e o *Glass Development Kit Preview*(GDK) também da API 19. Isso já deve habilitar a opção de projeto pra Glass durante a criação do projeto.

Pelo menos nas suas capturas de tela, ambos os requisitos não estão marcados como instalados.